# Should I always put a limit on a textarea?

Tags: html, textarea, maxlength

I have a question in regard to `textarea` character limits. I have a textarea where users can write articles of any length that they want; that is, they can make their article a sentence-long post or a really long article. I don't care how long the article is, as long as it's the length that the user wants. The only problem is I don't know if not inputting character limits at all is a bad idea. My question is this:

Does not placing a character limit to the textarea potentially lead to problems with people spamming a ton of text into the textarea and breaking something? I don't want to put a limit on the textarea, but I'm wondering if not placing a limit at all means that someone could come in and ruin it by putting too much text in there. So should I have SOMETHING working as validation for too much text in place?

Comment: I would never directly add the inputed value into the database. always parameterize and sanitize the values beforehand. get rid of the single quotes for example.

Comment: @MannySanchez I've been using mysqli_real_escape_string before inserting data into the database, but I hear that using prepared statements is safer. Do you recommend doing this and is it okay to leave it the way I have it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a limit would make sense for two main reasons:

1. Validation

   You have stated that already in your question. You maybe need to valiate your input regarding any corrupt characters or sql injections. If you do not limit it and you get many characters, your system may take to long to validate - this will depend wheather you check it locally or on server side.
2. Storage

     I am not sure how you will use the content, but in case of an CMS you have to save the posts in a database. A database will have different attributes with size settings. You will have to define the maximum size of your varchar in the database. Increasing that size will lead into potential errors and slow database.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the limit if you want to validate the text entered by the user.If you dont want to specify the limit the HTML code itself.You can write an regular expression in JavaScript code by specifying the type of text and length of text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to check if you really answer. Did you? Maybe a little bit more explanation is required.